# Подбор ближайшего формата листа. python

Tags: python

Получаю список листов для печати в пдф. Мне необходимо подобрать ближайший подходящий формат листа, по введенным размерам.
Функция которая на данный момент получилась, но она работает только если подаются точные цифры.

```
def get_paper_2(h1, w1):
    pd = System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog()
    ps= pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes
    d = {}
    for p in ps:
        if  "A" in p.PaperName or "А" in p.PaperName:
            h = round(p.Height*0.254)
            w = round (p.Width*0.254)
            if h1==h and w1==w:
                return p.PaperName
            elif h1==w and w1 == h:
                return p.PaperName
```

То есть например: есть формат листа `А2 = 594х420`, на вход я подаю например не точные данные, а например `595х419`, мне нужно чтобы формат был все равно А2

пробовал делать таким образом:

```
def compare_double(i1, i2):
    ma = (max(i1, i2))
    mi = (min(i1, i2))
    return ma/mi

d = {}
pd = System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog()
ps= pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes
for p in ps:
    if  "A" in p.PaperName or "А" in p.PaperName:
        h = round(p.Height*0.254)
        w = round (p.Width*0.254)

        g = compare_double(h, w)
        d[g] = [ p.PaperName, h, w]
        vv = max(d, key=lambda x: abs(x - compare_double(h1, w1)))
        print(d[vv])
```

Но это работает не корректно.
Как мне найти лист максимально соответствующий размерам, которые я подаю на вход?

Comment: а насколько неточными могут быть вводимые значения? если введут 297х315 например?

Comment: немного примерно +- 5 мм

Comment: Тогда сделайте просто что-то вроде `if X-10 < d < X+10`, где X длина по стандарту, а d - введенная длина. Т.е. сравнивайте не с точной длиной, а попадает  ли в нужный диапазон.

Comment: а, блин, точно, спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pformats = {297:'A4', 420:'A3', 210:'A5', 594:'A2'}

def find_closest(w: int, h: int) -> str:
    m = max(w, h)
    res = min(pformats.keys(), key=lambda x:abs(x-m))
    return pformats[res]
```

Тест:

```
print(find_closest(290, 210)) # A4
print(find_closest(302, 215)) # A4
print(find_closest(588, 405)) # A2
```

Comment: print(find_closest(290, 280)) # A4 - faltuire

Comment: print(find_closest(302, 215)) # A4 - faltuire. A4=297x210. 302 > 297,  215 > 210

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов - а теперь внимательно прочитайте вопрос. и потом мой комментарий к вопросу. а потом - ответ на мой комментарий.

Comment: Допустимая погрешность 5мм. Нет проверки малой стороны

Comment: Если перечитать все внимательно, речь шла о неточности вводимых данных. это значит, что пользователь может ввести формат А4 неточно на +- 5 мм на обе стороны. И при этом, если ввод будет _немного_ больше формата, все равно нужно выбрать ближайший.

Comment: Всё же не стоит упускать потенциальную ошибку. При квадрате проверка отработает без ошибок в функции, но с ошибкой в алгоритме.